# Stuck at colorful boot screen AFTER installing software to run an LCD 3.5" GPIO screen on my pi3

Tags: pi-3, gpio, boot, touchscreen, kali

the charger I am using is for an Amazon Alexa and it outputs 5.25V; there is enough power to power the pi, multiple peripherals, ethernet, HDMI, and the screen. BUT- when I install the software to make the screen run and actually display something instead of just white, I reboot and get stuck at the colorful loading screen, nothing happens afterward. Any ideas or help? I'm pretty darn sure it ISN'T the power supply (could be wrong :/)

Comment: `when I install the software` - what software? how did you install it? What "pattern" does the green LED flash with?

Comment: What is "_enough power_"? How much is it?